# Powershell - auto load changes to cmdlets/modules in terminal

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Tried `Import-Module <my module name>`, but the terminal session already in use doesn't reflect new changes in my cmdlet.

Closing and re-opening the terminal seems to be loading the latest changes, but it's not optimal during active development.

Any ideas how to automatically read/load the latest changes? TIA

---

Edit: ended up making an alias called `reload`

```
function Import-All-Modules { Import-Module * -Force }
Set-Alias -Name "reload" "Import-All-Modules"
```

Comment: Have you tried `Import-Module <my module name> -Force` ?

Comment: If the module is a binary it requires a new session otherwise as Olaf stated use `-Force`.

Comment: ha was so close. just tried `-Force` and it worked. Thank you!

Do you know if there's a way to make this process automatic?

Comment: `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Import-Module:Force'] = $true` can make it so it always uses it.

Comment: I'd assume he meant to update it automatically *without* the need to use `Import-Module` ....

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure but in that case I don't think so. Closest would be to set up a keybinding with `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler` or add it to `launch.json` in vscode but that is already part of a different question.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Ended up using

`function Import-All-Modules { Import-Module * -Force }
Set-Alias -Name "reload" "Import-All-Modules"`, and I can just run `reload` in my terminal now

Comment: that is surely the easiest solution to your problem, a function with a short name. if you wanted to try a keybinding you can do `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+Shift+Delete -ScriptBlock { Import-Module path\to\module -Force }`, `Ctrl+Shift+Delete` Chord combination can be changed for something better / easier

Comment: oh nice. Just tried `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`, it's even neat! Don't even have to type the cmd now. Thank you @SantiagoSquarzon!